# How to move the inverted menu items to left in Semantic UI?

Tags: html, css, node.js, semantic-ui

```css
i.icon {
    font-size: 2em;
}

.container.main {
    margin-top: 7.0em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blog App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" integrity="sha512-8bHTC73gkZ7rZ7vpqUQThUDhqcNFyYi2xgDgPDHc+GXVGHXq+xPjynxIopALmOPqzo9JZj0k6OqqewdGO3EsrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class= "ui top fixed inverted menu">
        <div class= "ui container">
            <div class= "header item">
                <i class= "pencil alternate icon"></i><a href= "/">Blog Site</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href= "/" class= "item">Home</a>
        <a href= "/blogs/new" class= "item">New Post</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code & I want to know how can I move the items to the left side of the menu?
I searched there docs, but couldn't find any solution..!!

Answer (score 0):

Just move them inside `.ui.container`:

```css
i.icon {
    font-size: 2em;
}

.container.main {
    margin-top: 7.0em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blog App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" integrity="sha512-8bHTC73gkZ7rZ7vpqUQThUDhqcNFyYi2xgDgPDHc+GXVGHXq+xPjynxIopALmOPqzo9JZj0k6OqqewdGO3EsrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class= "ui top fixed inverted menu">
        <div class= "ui container">
            <div class= "header item">
                <i class= "pencil alternate icon"></i><a href= "/">Blog Site</a>
            </div>
            <a href= "/" class= "item">Home</a>
            <a href= "/blogs/new" class= "item">New Post</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```